# Is it possible to draw a plot vertically with python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to draw a plot looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Comment: I believe the key word is "stripchart". Maybe you can adapt http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/animation/strip_chart_demo.html ?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just flip the x and y coordinates?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know what is your data for ... but here is a 'vertical' plot of *hypothetical* oxygen levels in near sea surface...

Note that nothing special is required.  Simply order your `x` and `y` values such that a line drawn from the first coordinate to the second and so on gives the vertical line you desire.

(The one special thing I've done here -- which may or may not be what you want -- is put the `xticks` at the top of the plot, using `tick_top`.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define data

Oxygen = [ 0.1 , 0.5, 1, 10, 15, 20, 15, 10, 1, 0.5, 0.5]
Depth  = [ 0,     1,  2,  4,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 40 ]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(Oxygen, Depth, 'go--')
ax.xaxis.tick_top()

ax.set_ylabel('depth')
ax.set_ylim(50, 0)
ax.set_xlim(0, 25)
ax.set_xlabel('Oxygen level [ppm]')

plt.show()
```

This yields:
[image]

I hope it helps ...

Comment: @wtm, notice that one little improvement you could do for aesthetic appeal, is to put the xtitle (Oxygen level) on top, instead of where it is now. But I won't spoil all the fun and let you discover alone ;-)